# "for good" expression in an unfortunate event?

Tags: phrases, expressions, history, semantics

I just heard an expression while watching a TV series yesterday.
Someone just died and they said:

> He is gone *for good*

I googled it and found that "for good" means "forever" in this context. But it still sounds odd to me to describe something unfortunate this way.

Is there a deeper reason behind this expression?

Comment: I can see why this would sound unusual, given its similarity to the expression "for _the_ good".  Still, I assure you, as a native speaker, that oddness didn't even occur to me until you asked your question. In context, I simply interpreted "for good" to mean "forever." But you've pointed out something rather peculiar indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*For good* simply means *forever* or *[for good and all](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+good)*.

> - **forever, permanently forever; permanently**
>     *I finally left home for good.
>
>     They tried to repair it many times before they fixed it for
>     good.*
> - **for good**  (British, American & Australian informal) **also *for good and    all***
>     (American informal) **forever**
>     *I'm leaving for good
>     this time.*
> - **permanently or forever**
>     *Now she says she's leaving him for good.*

This of course differs from *[for good](https://www.google.com/search?q=for%20good%20or%20evil&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb)* as opposed to *for evil.*

Comment: Interesting -- I've never heard of "for good and all." But I wonder how *that* expression came to mean forever?

Comment: You've given an explanation that is general reference. Despite it being the accepted answer, I don't see any explanation of "a deeper meaning behind this expression".

Answer (score 1):

I always understood the full expression to be '**For good or ill**'. In other words, regardless of his, her or its fortune.  Now often the word 'good' is a mispronunciation of 'God' (as in good-bye - God be with ye).  That adds quite a different slant on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow English "for good" reminds me of German endgültig which also has the meaning of "forever". But I think it would be quite a task to show that there might be a relationship between the German word element -gültig and English good. It would be necessary to see whether there are old variants of modern German endgültig in Old Saxon, Old Low Franconian/Frankish (Dutch), Old Frisian etc. An old variant of -gültig might have become similar to good and then been replaced by "good". But I don't think that it is possible to verify such an evolution. The written instances necessary for verifying such an evolution are too sparse.